Если я сделаю рекурсию с GoTo в LibreOffice Basic переполнится ли стек?
я занимаюсь разработкой таймера, который выполняет какое то действие каждый 30 мс. Сделать его я хочу только на LibreOffice Basic. Я делал рекурсию, но стек переполнялся, я делал циклы, но работают они медленнее, заметно даже глазом. Тогда мой науч. рук. нашел GoTo. С помощью GoTo я хочу реализовать рекурсию, я запускал этот код и стек не переполнялся, но мне интересно, может ли он переполнится и когда?
например вложенная рекурсия живет примерно 3-3.5к вызывов (проверял)
Sub loopWork
GoTo Label1
Label1:
    if stateMainTimer = 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    endif   
    GoTo Label2
Label2:
    loopWorkVoid()
    GoTo label1
End Sub

такая конструкция держится уже боле 35.000 вызовов

Не очень понятно, зачем вам тут именно рекурсия. И в вашем случае, обычный цикл(через goto) очень даже подходит.

Sub loopWork
Do While True
GoTo Label1
Loop
Label1:
if stateMainTimer = 2 Then
Exit Sub
endif
loopWorkVoid()
End Sub
не работает, если вы имели в виду внутри GoTo сделать цикл, то не подходит, так как становится сразу медленнее, что аж на глаз заметно
